# MATLAB spconvert in Python

Tags: python, matlab

Is there any Python (numpy,scipy) equivalent to  MATLAB's [`spconvert`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spconvert.html)

Comment: try looking into pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose a `foobar.txt` file with :

```
1 2  10
6 5  20
```

then use the `coo_matrix` function :

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
i,j,value=loadtxt('foobar.txt').T
m=coo_matrix((value,(i,j)))
print(m.todense())
```

for :

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  10.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  20.]]
```

Comment: Thanks,that was exactly what I need!